# Is it possible to redirect from one page in Project A to a page in Project B from within the same solution

Tags: c#, wpf

I have  two projects, Project A and Project B. Both are under same Solution. I want use a page of Project A in Project B. How to call that page from Project B. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a reference to Project A in your Project B. You can do this by RMC on a ProjectB and choosing Add reference... . Then in a new window go to Projects tab and choose Project A. After that, you can call the page in Project B:
Pseudo-code:

```
ProjectA.PageNamespace page = new ProjectA.PageNamespace()
```

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to acceess another solution forms you have 2 projects in the same solution.

To open a form from another project, you have to add a reference to that project.

In the first project, right-click on the References item in the Solution Explorer window.

Select the Add Reference option. Select the Projects tab and select the second project.

Click OK. Then, to access a form from the second project just use this:

Yourproject2.FormsName objName=new YourProject2.FormName();

objName.Show();

Answer (score 1):

First add a reference to your other project, then just call:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new ProjectB.page());
```